# How to check if string contains a certain word haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have the following String: "Do you like cats AND dogs"
I want to search the String for the word "AND" and replace it with "OR"

What I want to ask is if there is a function that can allow me to search and replace. I thought of using `elem` but I think it only works with Lists

Comment: notice that a `String` is a list of `Char` so functions working on `[]` would work on  `String` too. Since you are working with textual data, you should take a look to `Data.Text` (`text` package) which uses a better representation of textual data. If you aren't allowed to download packages or don't want to, I'd suggest to take a look to `words` function

Comment: This is a task that's better accomplished with generic Regex tools, not anything Haskell-specific. There's some overview about regex in Haskell [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Regular_expressions), as well as [a chapter in Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html) (both rather outdated now, but should still be useful).

Comment: While a `String` is a list, it's not the list of characters you want to work with, but the list of words in the string. As a rough approximation, you can use the `words` function to split `"Do you like cats AND dogs"` to `["Do","you","like","cats","AND","dogs"]`. (`words` won't handle punctuation in any useful way; it just splits on whitespace.)

Comment: and then use `break` with some pattern matching, and then `++`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the regex-applicative package:

```
Text.Regex.Applicative> replace ("OR" <$ string "AND") "cats AND dogs AND lizards"
"cats OR dogs OR lizards"
```